# Is there a way to continue to add graphics on a JPanel without having to redoing present graphics (ie. using the repaint() method)?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent, graphics2d

I've currently rewritten paintComponent() to paint three dots on my JPanel when the program begins to run. Each time the user presses a button I would like to add another dot. I understand I can keep a list of objects as a field and have paintComponent() iterate through that and paint each object, but I plan to have 1000s of iterations (this is the Chaos Game) and iterating through a large list each time I repaint can get costly in terms of time. I would like to avoid this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use a `BufferedImage` - Personally, I'd recommend trying to see how rendering 1000s of dots goes before you try to perform to much optimisation - it might surprise

Comment: Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of 1) iterating through a List of Objects and 2) painting to a BufferedImage. It contains some pro's/con's of each approach. So decide which approach is most relevant to your requirements.